# Create an array of objects by iterating through table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an HTML table and I want to iterate through its rows and create a collection or lets say an "array of objects".

For example:

```html
<table id="tbPermission">
  <tr>
    <th>User ID</th>
    <th>User Name</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Test1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to create a collection as below:

```
var trArray = [];
$('#tbPermission tr').each(function () {
    var tdArray = [];
    $(this).find('td').each(function () {

        // I want to create the array of objects here …
        tdArray.push();
    });

    // Final array
    trArray.push(tdArray);
});
```

The arrays may be like below:

```
tdArray : {'UserID' : '1', 'UserName' : 'Test1'};
```

and:

```
trArray : [
    {'UserID' : '1', 'UserName' : 'Test1'},
    {'UserID' : '2', 'UserName' : 'Test2'}
]
```

Comment: `push()` by itself doesn't push anything, you need to explicitly push an empty object: `push({})`

Comment: So whats the problem,  do you not know how to write the push commands?  Is that what your asking?  tdArray.push($(this).html()) maybe?

Comment: Why the need for arrays?  You could assign classes to the th's and td's and find what you need when you need it.  Unsure what problem your trying to solve.  Essentially, I feel like your creating a problem for yourself and now having trouble finding a solution, instead of not creating the problem in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I just want to create an array of objects from all cells of the table as i have trArray. Or if anyone can suggest any idea to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```
var trArray = [];
$('#tbPermission tr').each(function () {
    var tr =$(this).text();  //get current tr's text
    var tdArray = [];
    $(this).find('td').each(function () {
        var td = $(this).text();  //get current td's text
        var items = {}; //create an empty object
        items[tr] = td; // add elements to object 
        tdArray.push(items); //push the object to array
    });    
});
```

Here, I just created an empty object, filled object with references of tr and td, the added that object to the final array.

adding a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kp89fd74/)

Answer (score 1):

This solution relies on adding `thead` and `tbody` elements which is a good idea anyways since it indicates to the browser that the table actually is a "data" table and not presentational.

jQuery has a [`.map()`](https://api.jquery.com/map/) function. `map` is a basic function where you take an array and then replace the values with a the return value of a callback function - which results in a new array.

```
$([1,4,9]).map(function(){ return Math.sqrt(this) });
// [1, 2, 3]
```

`.toArray` converts the array like jQuery object we get into a "true array".

```js
jQuery(function(){
  
  var $table = $("#tbPermission");
  
  var headers = $table.find('thead th').map(function(){
    return $(this).text().replace(' ', '');
  });
  
  var rows = $table.find('tbody tr').map(function(){
    var result = {};
    var values = $(this).find('>td').map(function(){
      return $(this).text();
    });
    // use the headers for keys and td values for values
    for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
      result[headers[i]] = values[i];
    }
    
    // If you are using Underscore/Lodash you could replace this with
    // return _.object(headers, values);

    return result;
  }).toArray();

  
  // just for demo purposes
  $('#test').text(JSON.stringify(rows));
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tbPermission">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>User ID</th>
      <th>User Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Test1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<textarea id="test"></textarea>
```

If you for whatever reason cannot change the HTML you could use the index of the rows to differentiate between headers and rows of data:

```
  var headers = $table.find('tr:eq(0) th').map(function(){
    return $(this).text().replace(' ', '');
  });

  var rows = $table.find('tr:gt(0)').map(function(){
    // ...
  });
```

Comment: This is a bit longer than the other solutions but will work for whatever number of columns your table has.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest changing your html slightly.

```
<table id="tbPermission">
    <tr>
        <th>User ID</th>
        <th>User Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="userid">1</td>
        <td class="username">Test1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Then in your javascript when you want to get all the elements as an array you could do.

```
var userIdArray = $('#tbPermission .userid').map(function(userid){ return $(userid).html(); }).toArray();
```

This will find all elements with a class userid on the table, collect just the values, and .toArray() that result to get a basic javascript array.  You can then take that and manipulate it into whatever json structure you want, or you could possibly create your json object inside that map function.

Answer (score 0):

Check the console, you will get an array with the desired objects

```js
var arr = [];
$('#tbPermission tr:not(.header)').each(function() {
  var that = $(this);
  var id = that.find('td').eq(0).text();
  var name = that.find('td').eq(1).text();
  var obj = { 'userId': id , 'userName': name  };
  arr.push(obj);
});
console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tbPermission">
  <tr class="header">
    <th>User ID</th>
    <th>User Name</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Test1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Test2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

It's a bit tricky based on the given structure. You may have to modify the HTML a bit to map cells to headers, like below.

```js
var myArray = [];
  
$("#tbPermission").find("td").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this), obj = {};
    obj[$this.data("column")] = $this.text();
    myArray.push(obj);
});

alert ( JSON.stringify(myArray) );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tbPermission">
    <tr>
        <th>User ID</th>
        <th>User Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-column="User ID">1</td>
        <td data-column="User Name">Test1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Please give in some time to learn about [Array.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) and [Objects in Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects). Hope that helps.